# Logging errors using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, logging, error-handling

Currently have a script i'm running in Powershell which runs multiple scripts at the same time and logs what's been run with a custom message in a .txt file.

However, at the point of execution, I want to be able to also log, in a separate .txt file any errors that might occur, detailing the error, and which script it's affecting. I know I need to use a Try/Catch, but I can't think what to use for my Catch. Below is what I've got already:

```
ConvDlls;

clear;
$sqldir = "";
$DBPath = "";

$ConType = "ADS";



$SharedFunc = New-Object PelCFunc.SharedFunc;
$DS = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$Log = [MessageLogging.Msgs]::Instance;
$FullDBPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($DBPath,"PICS.Add");
$ConID = [guid]::NewGuid.ToString();
$Database = [PelCons.DatabaseManualMode]::Instance($ConID);



###Setup Database object
$Database.ConType = $ConType;
$Database.Connection = $SharedFunc.PelNewADSCon($FullDBPath);
Write-Output "Connection Created";


$Database.Connection.Close();
$Database.Connection.Open();

foreach ($file in [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($sqldir,"*.sql", 
[System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories))
{
$file = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new($file);


$Log.SetLogDir("");
$str_msg = "****This script has been run successfully****`r`n`r`nScript 
Run:$file`r`n`r`n$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName))";


$Log.AddMsg($str_msg);
Write-Output $str_msg;


$sql = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file.FullName);


$Database.Command.CommandText = $sql;
{

try{
$Database.Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

catch (exception ex)
{

}

}
}
$Database.Connection.Close();

Write-Output "Complete";
```

Comment: well in c# `catch(Exception e){MessageBox.Show(e.Message)}` returns any exception message thrown. so with this you can use your custom logging. like writing your 'e' value inside text file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$MyInvocation` variable (property `.MyCommand`) to get information about the script. In the catch block write your desired information in your desired file with e.g.

```
 out-file "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name).log"
```

You can also use the `$Error[0]` to get information about the last error.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've got it to produce my Errors.txt file, but it's not populating with anything, and there is an error in one of the scripts. What might I be missing?